# RSA encryption in React Native for Android and iOS

Tags: react-native, rsa, public-key-encryption

I would like to know how can I encrypt data with public key of RSA method and pass to Backend Side. Currently, I saw react-native-rsa-native library , install it in project and also link with command "react-native link react-native-rsa-native". But project still doesn't know the library. And shows the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateKeys' of undefined.
```

Here is my testing code according to the library documentation.

```
 RSA.generateKeys(4096) // set key size
.then(keys => {
console.log('4096 private:', keys.private); // the private key
console.log('4096 public:', keys.public); // the public key
RSA.encrypt(token, keys.public)
.then(encodedMessage => {
    console.log(`the encoded message is ${encodedMessage}`);
    RSA.decrypt(encodedMessage, keys.private)
    .then(decryptedMessage => {
        console.log(`The original message was ${decryptedMessage}`);
    });
});
```

});

Please suggest the ways that I can encrypt the data with React Native for RSA method.React native version of project is 0.59. For iOS, it supports starting from iOS version 9. Here is Android Version Info.

```
compileSdkVersion         = 29
minSdkVersion             = 19
targetSdkVersion          = 29
buildToolsVersion         = "28.0.3"
supportLibVersion         = "28.0.0"
supportAndroidVersion     = "28.0.0"
```

1. List item

[image]

Comment: Are you using Expo ? 
If yes you should consider ejecting expo because this module is not yet supported

Comment: Did you find solution to this problems? I am also facing same problem undefined (reading 'generateKeys')

Answer (score 1):

Seems linking issue. Can you try linking it manually in Pod file and check if works in the IOS simulator.

pod 'react-native-rsa-native',:path => '../node_modules/react-native-rsa-native'